# How to install XML parsers with Python

Tags: python

I'd like to use etree, expat or similar, though I understood etree is easier to use. But how do I install that when I already have Python 2.7.2 installed on Ubuntu 11.10?

All documentation I can find through Google suggests that xml parsing is available by default for Python. Or at least when I search for install xml parser python, or any combination of similar words, also including etree or expat I can't find what steps to take (a commandline install method).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like lxml.

Please have a look at the [lxml webpage](http://lxml.de/)

You can install it in ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

Comment: This will work for me. I already tried sudo apt-get install python-xml. Just one letter off from a solution...

Comment: One thing I should mention. I did have to follow the installation instructions from the lxml.de webpage. After just sudo apt-get install python-lxml Their test script still failed for me...

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for `etree`, you don't need to install anything, it's available in [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).