# What applications are removed when I upgrade to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

What all will be removed whenever I upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04? I've heard rumors that Banshee and Tomboy are going to be removed. What else will be removed?

Also, are there any major applications that won't work whenever I upgrade?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: what is your definition of "major applications" ?

Comment: "Major application" is vague, I guess. I mean things like VLC, Skype, WIne, things like that.

Bruno, all questions that I have not accepted an answer to are either unanswered or were answered in the comments under my question.

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, I will suggest you read the release notes before you install or upgrade. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/TechnicalOverview/Beta1

Comment: I read over that, but it didn't exactly mention a list of removed applications.

Comment: I know that Banshee will be removed but what about all the music files I have ripped using Banshee? Will those remain?

Comment: Those files will still be there. Truthfully, whenever I upgraded to 12.04, I didn't lose Banshee at all. Rhythmbox was installed but I kept Banshee. I guess the release install of 12.04 does not include Banshee by default, and that's what they meant.

The short answer because I tend to ramble: your music will be ok :)

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I can upgrade without fear of losing all my music now. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The release-upgrader will not remove banshee or tomboy unless you removed "universe"
from your sources.list (e.g. via the Software Sources tool).

In general it will not remove software unless there is a conflict or the software is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

Tomboy and Banshee data **aren't lost during the upgrade**, only the application will be removed.  FreeRDP and Remmina will replace rdesktop and vinagre. Rhythmbox will replace Banshee. Gbrainy and Tomboy will be removed.
https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-p-default-apps

After the upgrade both applications will remain easily installable from the Ubuntu Software Center for those who prefer to use them.

Comment: Are these the only two applications that will be removed? That more-or-less is my question.

Comment: added more details to answer you.

Comment: Thank you. Why do people out there keep insisting that applications will *not* be removed during an upgrade.

Comment: Upgrades will generally *not* remove packages, unless those packages conflict with something the upgrade needs to install.  Neither Banshee nor Tomboy conflict with anything, so they should remain.

What might occur is that Tomboy and Banshee *might* have been marked as ‘automatically installed’, and since `ubuntu-desktop` no longer depends on them, they're candidates for removal.

Answer (score 2):

I asked Canonical support about this a few days ago. I noticed Banshee (replaced with Rhythmbox) and Vinagre had been removed. Here's the reply I got:

> Here are some links which should provide you with the information you
>   are looking for:
>
> - [UDS-P "Default Apps" Meeting notes](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-p/meeting/19442/desktop-p-default-apps/)
> - ["Default Apps" Blueprint on Launchpad](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-p-default-apps)
>
> Part of the change was triggered during the discussion at Ubuntu
>   UDS P Orlando ( [1.5GB DVD Image by default](http://youtu.be/8oyzZqBpPnw) ).

Answer (score 0):

Before upgrading system Ubuntu will inform you that you need to delete a few applications, but you will be all the applications back into the system after first update from Update Manager. You should all stay the entire application (so at least I was).