# If I upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 will I lose my Tomboy notes?

Tags: upgrade, 12.04, tomboy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What applications are removed when I upgrade to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111163/what-applications-are-removed-when-i-upgrade-to-12-04)

I use Tomboy extensively and keep lots of random, connected things there I would not want to bother replicating or backing up too heavily.

If I /will/ lose them when mono is removed and tomboy is dropped, what can I do to preserve my data?  I'm curious about the actual mechanism here---does an upgrade destroy my current Tomboy installation, or is it just the case that Tomboy isn't installed by default for /new/ installs, but that the stuff I already have is preserved under an upgrade situation?